# SSH-256/512 RSA taking "long" to login

Tags: ssh, putty, sha1, sha-2, pageant

Up to now, I have been using putty + pageant 0.66 to ssh from my Win 10 client to a couple of Linux servers, as in

```
   Comp A                         Comp B                    Comp C
Win 10, Msys2   ----------->   Ubuntu 18.04   ----------->   RHEL6
     |             Warning                     No warning      ^
     |                                                         |
     |---------------------------------------------------------|
                             No warning
```

As described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57662255/agent-key-rsa-sha256-returned-incorrect-signature-type/61249169#61249169), I was getting a warning about using SHA-1 when connecting A to B.

To fix this, I started [using putty + pageant 0.73](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61249169/2707864).
Now each ssh authentication from A to B takes about 27s. Before, it was immediate.
This is usually not a serious issue.
But once in a while it may become a significant inconvenience.

When authenticating from A to C, connection is still immediate.

**I wonder whether this is expected, and if it can be mended some way.**

Comment: Are you talking about connection from A to B, or about connections from B to C?

Comment: @user1686 - Good question... please see updated OP.

Comment: Your issue here, and on [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57662255/6819406), appears to arise from using an insecure SHA1 based key, as no SSH server should currently support SHA1 because it's a security risk.

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question...
All processors were busy at 100% performing calculations by other users in server B.
I tested SSHing to a couple of other servers and it worked immediately.